# "Communiqué"? English?

Tags: word-usage

Is the word "Communiqué" an English word? It originated from French but does it have mainstream English usage? I have used it in my scholarship essay for an English writing course - Well I intend to (use it).. I won't submit unless I know it's appropriate.

Comment: Depends on how you define ‘mainstream’. It’s not a word you’re likely to hear used by your average teenager when talking with mates; but it’s perfectly likely to occur in an essay or other (semi-)formal writings. For an English writing course, it’s fine.

Comment: Yes. It is one of those foreign words which has acquired a very specific meaning in English and is mostly used as part of diplomatic language. 'The rebel leaders issued a communiqué to the international media with their demands listed'.

Comment: To use a foreign word that has not yet gained full acceptance into English, put it in italics (as per the _Chicago Manual of Style_). However, if you can find the word in _Merriam-Webster's Collegiate Dictionary_ (_communiqué_ is in there), consider it a fully adopted word; there is no need for italics or any special formatting.

Comment: @ Theodore Bronda Thng is, there is no formatting available/allowed. Will it be acceptable then? Thanks!

@Janus & WS2 Thought so too! Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to the full Oxford English Dictionary, ***communiqué*** has been used in English newspapers and books since the mid-nineteenth century. One illustrative example:

> 1882   W. Besant **All Sorts of Men** III. xlv. 194   *The result appeared in a long communiqué which attracted general and immediate interest*.

It is nowadays quite common in the linguistic registers of History, and International Relations, and appears frequently enough in English newspapers and journals. It should be perfectly appropriate in any academic writing on similar subjects.

Comment: Exacly what I wanted (to hear? lol) Thanks immensely!